# Get property name from Func<t, T>

Tags: c#, properties, func

How can I get the property name from `Func<T, TResult>`?

There many posts how to get prop name but from `Expression` and not from `Func`

```
_resultViewModel.SelectMeasurement(si => si.Height, vm => vm.HeightImg); // this is usage... I need to get "Height"

public void SelectMeasurement(Func<ScanInfo, double> measurement, Func<ResultViewModel, ImageSource> image)
{
    //some stuff
}
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression

Comment: That's a closure, not a property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get "property name" from `Func<T, TResult>`, because there are no any "property" and any "name", when delegate is constructed.

Moreover, delegate can get its return value in some different way, instead of member access:

```
Func<Foo, string> = foo => "bar";
```

This differs from the expressions case (`Expression<Func<T, TResult>>`), because expressions represent some code, which could be compiled into delegate, and could be parsed.

Comment: ok, thanks for reply. If i use ` Expression<Func<T, TResult>>`, how can i get `Func<T, TResult>` from expression?

Comment: @demo: you can compile it: `yourExpressionVar.Compile()`. Note, that it rather slow, and it is better to think about caching of results.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you are going to work with simple delegates that are meant to access model properties then you can use a method similar to this:

```
private static string GetFuncPropertyName<T, TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expr)
{
    if (expr.Body is not MemberExpression memberExpression)
        throw new ArgumentException($"The provided expression contains a {expr.GetType().Name} which is not supported. Only simple member accessors (fields, properties) of an object are supported.");
    return memberExpression.Member.Name;
}
```

You can pass regular lambda delegates into it:

```
private class MyClass { public string MyProperty { get; set; } }
...
var propertyName = GetFuncPropertyNameT<MyClass, string>(m => m.MyProperty);
```

If you are not sure, you will have to get the actual method body `func.GetMethodInfo().GetMethodBody();`, parse IL bytes to a string (which is a non-trivial task) and then interpret it. For reference you can look at: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/14058/parsing-the-il-of-a-method-body